# jquery how to passing value into input type=text

Tags: jquery

```
Date: <input type="text" id=" ">

var startDate = new Date(2012,1,20);
$('#date-start')
.datepicker()
.on('changeDate', function(ev){
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > endDate.valueOf()){
        $('#alert').show().find('strong').text('The start date must be before the end date.');
    } else {
        $('#alert').hide();
        startDate = new Date(ev.date);
        $('#date-start-display').text($('#date-start').data('date'));
    }
    $('#date-start').datepicker('hide');
});
```

i'm trying to use this jquery datepicker.
how to passing value date output into input type=text

Answer (score 0):

You have left the id `blank`, assign some `id` to input type=text to which you need to `assign` date.

Assuming `$('#date-start').data('date')` will give you required date.

*Html*

```
<input type="text" id="txtDate">
```

*Javascript*

```
$('#txtDate').val($('#date-start').data('date'));
```

or

```
$(':text').val($('#date-start').data('date')); // will assign date to all text fields
```

Comment: thank you Aidil. how to passing that value to sql statement using variable sem. Example rsResult.Open "SELECT * from d_answer where semester='" & sem & "' order by questionid,semester",conn